# Zend Framework problem creating actions through command line

Tags: zend-framework, bash

I am trying to create actions in my project by using,

`zf create action add edit`

however my command line outputs this message,

```
                           An Error Has Occurred                            
 A project profile was not found.                                       

Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.9.7
Details for action "Create" and provider "Action"
  Action
    zf create action name controller-name[=index] view-included[=1] module
```

I am running, Zend Framework 1.9 on Max OSX 10.6.2, does any one know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create your project with the commandline tool as well? If not this is likeley the problem as using the tool requires an up-to-date `.zfproject.xml` file in the projects directory.

```
// example project sturcture

project-folder/
  .zfproject.xml
  application/
  library/
  public/
```

Comment: I did create it through the command line but I have no projects fold or xml file, is there anything I can do to rectify this?

Comment: by project folder i mean the folder in which `application`, `library`, etc.. exist in - the top level dir. in this directory you should have that xml file i mentioned. further you need to execute the task in question from this directory.

Comment: thanks sorted now, i was not in my project in cmdline, such stupidity grrr! Thanks for your help

Comment: can i get some "answer love"? :-)